# How to generate CSS from Sass in Bulma

Tags: css, sass, bulma

This is my first time working with Scss, although I have run the command in terminal to convert a simple `input.sass` to `output.css` in the case of other libraries, it seems a little bit difficult, since it's new to me.

I have a profile with `index.html` which should require a `style.css`, but I need this `style.css` to be generated from [Bulma](http://bulma.io) directory which is currently in this format:

```
index.html 
vendors
    bulma
       css
          bulma.css
          bulma.css.map
        sass
            base
              _all.sass
              generic.sass
              helpers.sass
              minireset.sass
            components
            elements
            grid
            layout
            utitlities
            bulma.sass
```

The problem here is that, unlike the `sass input.scss output.css` example which converts Scss files to CSS, the above seems complicated.

I don't know which file to convert, or if I should alter the Sass file and modify them but do I save the output in individual CSS file or one master style...

Answer (score 2):

in every sass directory such as base, components and so on, they all have `_all.sass` file. which include all of the files in that directory. So, all you need is to include one `_all.sass` file from every folder within sass folder.

So in your sass file, that you will watch with sass gem, make includes for all fo the `_all.sass`.
Something like this would work.

```
@import "utilities/_all"
@import "base/_all"
@import "elements/_all"
@import "components/_all"
@import "grid/_all"
@import "ayout/_all"
```

Also, I am not 100% sure, but I think it is a bad idea to mix sass with scss, so my advice would be to do something like this:

In your sass folder of your project create a sass file and name it `styles.sass`. In that file write imports to all the `_all.sass` files.

And then just go do this in the terminal:  `sass --watch sass:css`

Comment: Thanks `+1`,  but I have just one more question that isn't clear to me. I understand what you said and I have to include all `_all.sass` from each component's files, but to where? I have `public_html/css/style.css` which should this `styles.sass` live in the directory?

Comment: So ```public_html/css/style.css``` is your destination style sheet. In your source style sheet, which is ```styles.sass``` include all the ```_all.sass``` files. and when you compile all of that code will be in your destination style sheet. Take a look at bulma's GitHub repository, especially [bulms.sass](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/bulma.sass)

Comment: Sorry, this did not work. I have gem and sass installed, but when I do ` sass input.scss output.css`  as seen in http://sass-lang.com/guide I get errors, that some color is undefined and `!is not valid`. 

For more information, I have created a styles.sass (tried with scss) inside vendors/bulma/sass/directory and in this file I only have `@import "bulma"` command, but then I did ` sass styles.scss style.css` but no effect except an error. Let's see if someone can fix this

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417918/error-for-invalid-css-when-trying-to-compile-sass will help?