# Error for invalid css when trying to compile sass

Tags: css, sass

I am new to sass, after having downloaded bulma, installed gem, and sass, I tried to compile a default sass file with `sass style.scss style.css`, here is my directory structure

[image]

But I get errors likes this:

```
/*
Error: Invalid CSS after "$pink": expected selector or at-rule, was ": #ffb3b3 "
        on line 2 of styles.scss

1: $blue: #72d0eb 
2: $pink: #ffb3b3 
3: $orange: #FFA500
4: $family-serif: "Georgia", serif
5: 
6: $danger: $orange
7: $family-primary: $family-serif 

Backtrace:
styles.scss:2
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1207:in `expected'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1137:in `expected'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:42:in `parse'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:406:in `_to_tree'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:381:in `_render_with_sourcemap'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:298:in `render_with_sourcemap'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:391:in `run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:63:in `process_result'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in `parse'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in `parse!'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/sass-3.4.23/bin/sass:13:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/sass:23:in `<main>'
*/
body:before {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
  content: "Error: Invalid CSS after \"$pink\": expected selector or at-rule, was \": #ffb3b3 \"\A         on line 2 of styles.scss\A \A 1: $blue: #72d0eb \A 2: $pink: #ffb3b3 \A 3: $orange: #FFA500\A 4: $family-serif: \"Georgia\", serif\A 5: \A 6: $danger: $orange\A 7: $family-primary: $family-serif "; }
```

I can't seem to find a fix for this

Answer (score 2):

Try terminating the line by a semi-colon (;)

For example -

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;
```

Comment: I tried it, I even created two files `styles.sass` and `style.scss` and put semi colons at the end of the variable values, but I get errors saying invalid css, `expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";" on line 1 of styles.sass`

Answer (score 2):

You're compiling a *real* Sass file, with the [Sass indented syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) (no braces, no semi-colon, indentation alone is sufficient).
But the extension of your file is `*.scss`, meant for CSS-like syntax (there's a c, see ^^)

Either rename your file to `styles.sass` with an a or write your styles as you'd write CSS (but with nested rules, variables, etc provided by this preprocessor :) )

Sass the compiler compiles both Sass indented syntax and Scss one, which is not straightforward...

EDIT: try to compile a plain CSS file (no variable, no mixin, no nesting just CSS) renamed to `.scss`. CSS is valid LESS and Scss so if it doesn't compile, the problem isn't with your file.
You can also try to compile the content of your file in http://www.sassmeister.com and play with the options.

Comment: I don't understand, if you check out http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/ in the final example, shows that I need to include the code in my "sass" file, which can only mean `foo.sass` as for the indentation, I just copy-pasted it as is. What can I do more than that?

Comment: That's what I'd do too. But test that your compiler is working fine with a CSS file renamed as `*.scss`. Also what happens if you add your variables after 1st line of https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/bulma.sass and then try to compile that file?